# Generate unit test for all classes

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if there's a way from VS2017 Enterprise to automatically generate Tests for all the classes presents inside the project.
I'm aware I can right click on a class definition then do

[image]

But I was wondering if there's a project way to do so